# Laravel - npm run dev - Failed to find '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, sass

I have created a project in Laravel 8, and when I run `npm run dev` it throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'
  in [
    /Users/me/Laravel/<projectName>/resources/sass
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (/Users/me/Laravel/<projectName>/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-12-30T08_24_47_410Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-12-30T08_24_47_441Z-debug.log
```

My `resources/sass/app.scss` looks like this:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css';
```

I've tried with `@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'` as well, but that doesn't work either.

I can see `all.min.css` in the tree when I follow the path `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css` so I know for a fact that it's there.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have the pro license?

Comment: remove `@` i guess `@import '~fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css';`

Comment: I do have the pro license yes. I've also set up my project by following `https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers`

Comment: If I remove `@` I get the same error, just with `Failed to find '~fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'`

Comment: @Nissen what is your `Font Awesome`  version?

Comment: The `package.json` in my node_modules says `5.15.1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the ~ before the import line:

```
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css';
```